# Deploying a custom Shopify APP built with Shopify CLI Node to Firebase

Tags: firebase, next.js, shopify-app

I have created a custom Shopify app using Shopify CLI. I need to deploy this app on Firebase.
I am using the Firestore database.
I tried deploying it to Heroku and that works well.
In order to deploy it to Firebase, I tried `next export` and pointed the `out` directory in firebase.json. but it didn't work.
Is there any way to deploy a Shopify custom app built with Shopify CLI Node on Firebase?
Thank you.

`package.json` scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon ./server/index.js --watch ./server/index.js",
    "build": "next build && next export",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./server/index.js"
  },
```

`firebase.json` scripts

```
 "hosting": {
    "public": "out",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "nextjs-server"
      }
    ]
  }
```